# I want to drag image into another element in React.js (mobile view)

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I want to drag image into another element in React.js.
It works well on PC but not working on mobile.
How can I solve it?
[This is what I want.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ziJL2.png)

I want it to works well on both PC and mobile.
Please feel free to contact me.
Thanks